# Is there a way to make a file "ungitable"?

Tags: git, file, permissions

I'm making a server, and I would really like to put it up on github, but I have a file containing the hashed passwords, don't want to put this file on the web for security reasons.

What I usually do when I commit my work is:

```
git add *
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Now, if I would do that on my server project, the password file would get uploaded as well! Is there a way to make it so that when I type those commands, the password file won't get uploaded?

Comment: You could "ignore" that file.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.gitignore` file in the root of your repository and put the path to the file (relative to the root of the repository) you don't want to be committed in it. git will then ignore the file in all operations.

You can read more about how to do this [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/). There are also some links to example files at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file to the `.gitignore` so it will be undetectable by git.

If you still want the file in the repository (with default values for example) you should use the `assume-unchanged` flag on the tracked file.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]